# The weirdest VBA issue I have ever seen (VBASigned Possible Bug on Boolean Condition)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

In MS Word I added some code to see if a document is missing its digital signature, or at least I thought I did. I've decided to share before testing this on other systems.

```
Sub test()
    If Not ThisDocument.VBASigned Then
        Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Problem: The code above produces the same result irrespective of whether or not the document has a digital signature.  If I modify the code by removing the `Not` I still get unexpected results.

I've tried to coerce things by doing things like:

```
If Not CBool(ThisDocument.VBASigned) Then
```

But more surprisingly, the following code also fails:

```
Sub test()
    Dim isSigned As Boolean
    isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned

    If Not isSigned Then
        Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Even though `ThisDocument.VBASigned` AND `isSigned` are both `TRUE`...
[image: snapshot of my code running]
but if change `isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned` to `isSigned = True` then everything works as expected.

Can anyone confirm this?
Any thoughts?

---

Edits below answer some of the questions:

1. Yes, using `Option Explicit`, Yes also tried Debug.
   This code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub test()
       Dim isSigned As Boolean
       isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned
       Debug.Print ThisDocument.VBASigned
       If Not isSigned Then
           Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   Produces this output:

   > True
   >     I am NOT signed
2. Testing: `True * 0 - 1`.

   ```
   Sub test()
       Dim isSigned As Boolean
       isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned
       Debug.Print ThisDocument.VBASigned
       If Not (isSigned * 0 - 1) Then
           Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

   Produces this (expected) output:

   > True

---

Edit: interesting article by Raymond Chen that might provide some further insights as to how this happened: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923

In short, as the Windows operating system evolved it included different types of booleans: int > byte > variant

Comment: I don't relay on conditions that are not that clear. Why not to only `If ThisDocument.VBASigned = True Then ...` or `If ThisDocument.VBASigned = False Then ...` ? I think adding a `Not` makes the boolean far way tanggled than it should be and it could be a logical condition that's failing.

Comment: **How** `isSigned` gets to be `True` wouldn't affect the code's actions after it **is** set to `True`.  (It's just a variable - it has no memory of what happened to it in the past.)  Are you sure you didn't manually set `isSigned` to `True` after stepping into the `If` statement while it was `False`?  Have you included `Option Explicit` to ensure there are no hidden characters in your variable names?

Comment: @Sgdva either way it should work.  "If Not True Then"   is   the same as "If False Then"  and is quite common.

Comment: @YowE3K I hear ya.  Shouldn't make a difference but it does.  Definitely DID NOT accidentally change anything, I've tested this many ways with many permutations and the issue (as written above) is 100% reproducible on my system.

Comment: @SlowLearner Indeed, but I have seen some native functions in VBA to fail if some weird logic is used and had to come up with my own. Whenever you're able to, try to keep the logic simple. I don't see why you'd need to use the Not True instead of False

Comment: See what happens if you change it to `isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned * 0 - 1`.  And also see what happens if you delete the line and retype it.

Comment: @Sgdva IMO it's not usually a good idea to use expressions like `booleanexpression = True` (which is just equivalent to `booleanexpression`) and `booleanexpression = False` (which is just equivalent to `Not booleanexpression`) - it just makes the code harder to read.  (e.g. `If Visible Then` is usually easier to read then `If Visible = True Then`, and `If Not Visible Then` is usually easier to read then `If Visible = False Then`)

Comment: First step. Debug.Print ThisDocument.VBASigned

Comment: @YowE3K why would I do that?  true * 0 = false * 0

Comment: I was hoping to see whether there was something invalid in the line that was confusing things - by just editing it to force it to be -1 (i.e. True) it may give us info - i.e. you say `isSigned = True` works correctly, but my statement should be forcing exactly the same thing to occur and, if still does something funny, we learn a bit more.

Comment: Also try deleting and retyping the `If Not isSigned Then` line.  (It seems weird, but there have been several cases over the last couple of months where simply retyping what appears to be the exact same line has resolved inexplicable problems.)

Comment: @YowE3K I noticed this issue in a different project then rewrote it in a new project which was blank, then I posted here.  By the way, there is a pretty cool VBA decompiler by Orlando - works well, fixes the issues you speak of: http://cpap.com.br/orlando/VBADecompilerMore.asp.

Comment: OK - I am completely stumped.  (I wish I had a file with a VBASigned of True so that I could test it better - this is intriguing!)

Comment: @YowE3K is it possible to open a private chat - I don't know how to do it...

Comment: @SlowLearner - have you actually tried `If isSigned = False`? This was a known bug in Access VBA some years ago.

Comment: @Skippy - just tested and yes that actually works as expected, but I'm more concerned about why the code posted in the question does not work as expected and if anyone is able to reproduce. Thanks,

Comment: @Skippy - would that bug cause the code to behave differently depending on how the boolean variable was being set to `True`?

Comment: @SlowLearner - I wouldn't have been able to use chat earlier (work firewall blocks it) but I'm home now - we could possibly use the [VBA Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge) if you are still around and want to chat.

Comment: @peh - thanks for fixing the code, wouldn't let me do it tried all sorts of things.

Comment: I did some tests and can confirm @SlowLearner's issue. Using `isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned` or even with `isSigned = cBool(ThisDocument.VBASigned)` let `If Not isSigned Then` fail. Using `isSigned = True` doesn't fail on the `If`. This looks like a strange bug in Office because both `ThisDocument.VBASigned` and `isSigned` are of the type boolean.

Comment: This looks like a bug in **Word** only. If I test the same code in Excel with `ThisWorkbook.VBASigned` instead of `ThisDocument.VBASigned` it works like it should. Therefore I bet on a Word bug.

Comment: Thanks @Peh - glad you could verify.

Comment: @SlowLearner what is the output for `Debug.Print TypeName(ThisDocument.VBASigned)` and `Debug.Print TypeName(isSigned)` in Word VBA Project?

Comment: @omegastripes  here is the output `?TypeName(ThisDocument.VBASigned)` returns `Boolean`

Comment: @Sgdva - I said earlier that it isn't a good idea to use things like `booleanexpression = False` instead of `Not booleanexpression`, but in this situation it looks like that solution would have worked - because `ThisDocument.VBASigned` wasn't a "true" `Boolean` value (it is just a `Boolean` variable containing a numeric value).

Comment: @YowE3K You know, microsoft ;) Nevertheless, your solution is really expanded, thanks for clarifying what's happening according to the documentation!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After playing with a digitally signed version of a document that SlowLearner supplied me, I have determined that Word's VBASigned is returning a `1` when it is signed.

This then leads to problems in the `If` statement, because `Not 1` is equal to `-2`, and `Not 0` is equal to `-1` - thus leading to `Not VBASigned` returning a non-zero (i.e. non-False) value in all cases.

---

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836069.aspx) states that `VBASigned` is a read-only Boolean, and the type of variable returned has been confirmed (by `TypeName(ThisDocument.VBASigned)`) to be `Boolean`, but it appears it should be treated as a numeric value instead.

---

An additional interesting fact is that `CBool(ThisDocument.VBASigned) * 1` gives an answer of `1`, while a `CBool(1) * 1` gives an answer of `-1`.  So it seems that, when VBA decides that a value is already a `Boolean` (such as `ThisDocument.VBASigned` is meant to be), it doesn't bother to do any conversions.  But, when the parameter to `CBool` is not a `Boolean`, it converts a non-zero value to be `-1`.

---

Code that would work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myVBASigned As Integer
    Dim isSigned As Boolean
    myVBASigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned 'Store as Integer
    isSigned = myVBASigned               'Convert to a "true" Boolean

    If Not isSigned Then                 'Use the "true" Boolean
        Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This basically explains the behavior which is more than I expected to achieve :-) thanks!

Comment: I can confirm this. But this still is a bug in Word then.

Comment: @Peh yup, still a bug in word - but really nice to know what the bug is... knowing that it is 1 instead of -1 gives me confidence because I better understand the issue.

Comment: @SlowLearner - I have added some code to the answer that will convert the VBASigned to a "true" `Boolean` by first passing it through an `Integer` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Testing this against Excel show that this is a bug in Word.

Assuming we have new documents with VBA enabled and VBA signed:

Using in Excel:

```
Sub testExcel()
    Dim isSigned As Boolean
    isSigned = ThisWorkbook.VBASigned
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.VBASigned
    If Not isSigned Then
        Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
    Else
        Debug.Print "I AM signed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Results in

> True
>   I AM signed

But using the same in Word

```
Sub testWord()
    Dim isSigned As Boolean
    isSigned = ThisDocument.VBASigned
    Debug.Print ThisDocument.VBASigned
    If Not isSigned Then
        Debug.Print "I am NOT signed"
    Else
        Debug.Print "I AM signed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Results in

> True
>   I am NOT signed

This clearly shows that there is a bug in Word.

---

This was tested with

- Windows 10 x64
- Office Professional Plus 2016

  - Version 1703 Build 7967.2139
  - German
  - 64 Bit Office

Comment: SlowLearner and I have just been discussing this in a chat - we found that Word's VBASigned is returning `1` if True rather than `-1`

Comment: Thanks Peh - good to know, sad that MS Word is so unloved.  Strange bug to have in one component of an integrated office suite... just saying.